# Doctrine 2 How to set an entity table name at run time (Zend 2)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, scalability

I'm building a product with Zend 2 and Doctrine 2 and it requires that I have a separate table for each user to contain data unique to them. I've made an entity that defines what that table looks like but how do I change the name of the table to persist the data to, or in fact retrieve the data from, at run time?

Alternatively am I going to be better off giving each user their own database, and just changing which DB I am connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

I'd question the design-choice at first. What happens if you create a new user after runtime. The table has to be created first? Furthermore, what kind of data are you storing, to me this sounds like a pretty common multi-client capabilities. Like:

```
tbl_clients    
- id
- name

tbl_clientdata
- client_id
- data_1_value
- data_2_value
- data_n_value
```

Comment: It's mostly e-commerce data, products, orders, customers etc. It will be accessed via an API so I don't believe it will ever be the case that a process is being run that doesn't already have the user setup

Comment: Sam is correct.  You certainly can't do what you want to do with Doctrine.  An entity must map to one table, as the EntityManager maintains and identity map.  With multiple tables, you'd end up with two entities with the same id, which will cause things to break horribly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to silo users data, you'd have to go the separate databases route.  But that only works if each "user" is really independent of each other.  Think very hard about that.

If you're building some kind of software-as-a-service, and user A and user B are just two different customers of yours, with no relationship to each other, then an N+1 database might be appropriate (one db for each of your N users, plus one "meta" database which just holds user accounts (and maybe billing-related stuff).

I've implemented something like this in ZF2/Doctrine2, and it's not terribly bad.  You just create a factory for EntityManager that looks up the database information for whatever user is active, and configures the EM to connect to it.  The only place it gets a bit tricky is when you find yourself writing some kind of shared job queue, where long-running workers need to switch database connections with some regularity -- but that's doable too.